# Hide the file path on the title bar in Sublime Text

Tags: title-bar, sublime-text

I've been using Sublime Text on Linux. I now switched to Windows, and the file path on the title bar is different from Linux: Sublime Text always shows the complete path on the tile bar.

Can I hide it like it is under Linux?

Comment: What's the deal with questions about Sublime and the title bar today? http://superuser.com/questions/690531/is-it-possible-for-sunlime-text-3-to-hide-the-file-path-on-the-title-bar-in-the — the full path to the file path is shown in Linux, OS X *and* Windows.

Comment: @slhck♦I like the title bar has no file path and only contains the filename ,what is your puzzle about my quetion

Comment: Why would you do that (switch to Windows from Linux)...!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Sublime Text behavior is the same on Windows, Linux and OS X. It does not show the full path by default.

To override this, add the following to your settings:

```
"show_full_path": false
```

Or remove the setting altogether. The default will be not to show the complete path.

Comment: Thank you,my dear friend my home tongue is simplied chinese ,so sometimes I cannot show what i want to do .So i hope you canforgive me

Comment: Don't worry about your language. If you have a question like this, or if you have troubles explaining, it always helps to include a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[SublimeOverlay](https://github.com/mikadev001/SublimeText-Overlay)**.
There's an option in settings window to hide the title.

P.S. I'm the author of this program.

Comment: Please clarify your answer (e.g. so it's useful even if/when the link becomes obsolete).  Also AFAIU he doesn't want to hide the title, but to shorten it so it only displays the "basename".