# Sublime Text: show project title before filepath in taskbar title (Windows)

Tags: windows, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Because my local server is multiple directories deep, I just see something like `C:/www/projects/myp...` for each sublime window, even though the full title includes the project name appended (e.g. `C:/www/projects/myproject (My Project)`). Ideally the order should be switched to `My Project - C:/www/projects/myproject` so that the project name is visible without having to open the window.

Comment: Maybe [Hide the file path on the title bar in Sublime Text](http://superuser.com/a/690564/376602)?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue on the project's GitHub page asking for the [ability to configure window title content format](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1179). So far, I've seen no official response since that issue was created 9 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences.sublime_settings -> "show_project_first": true

Comment: This works amazing! Thanks